# How to fill an array with an object pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a pattern with default values which one looks like this:

```
DataStructure.prototype.modelPattern = {
    param1: 0,
    param2: 1,
    ...
    param462: 1500
};
```

This pattern represents the structure of a so called "model". Due to I need more than one model I need to create more of those "modelPattern" objects. They all get saved in an array within the same class:

```
DataStructure.prototype.models = [];
```

So this cannot work:

```
this.models[rightPlace] = this.modelPattern;
```

... due to this just saves the reference to the "modelPattern" object into the array.

So I need to create new objects of "modelPattern" and save them into the array. I already tried those things:

```
new modelPattern;
modelPattern.create();
```

This is my first OOP javascript project so I guess I missed something that causes my problem. I need the solution with the pattern due to I don't want to define that extremely long thing over and over in different methods where I need it.

Comment: Your question makes me think that you are taking the wrong approach with your OOP, but I can't be sure with the little code that I see. Do you really want all new DataStructure objects to share the same models array?

Comment: What do you even mean by "model pattern"?

Comment: Totally might be that I use OOP in the wrong way. :D I think I will understand it with my trial and error method.

Concerning your question: I don't have more than one DataStructure object. Also I only have one models array. The "modelPattern" just got all the default values saved in it.

But as you can see below I already built a solution with a function to generate the object and write the default values into it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with functions.
e.g.

```
function createModelPattern(name, start, end) {
  var i, j, model = {};
  for(i = start, j = 0; i <= end; i++, j++) {
    model[name + i] = j;
  }
  return model;
}

console.log(createModelPattern("param", 1, 10));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me a lot. I didn't know that I can create the variables of an object with a simple loop. I thought I need to declare them before. It works with a modified version of your loop. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand the difference between object `prototype` and `instance`? The `prototype` is only useful if you're going to have multiple `instances`, else you can use a single object (just making sure).
Why not simply store your modelPattern in a separate prototype? It's definitely more modular...

```
function ModelPatternConstruct () {
  this.param1 = 0;
  this.param2 = 1;
  //etc.
}
```

You can make modelPatterns based off of the constructor. They will inherit the prototype's values. Finally, if you want your models to be accessible through named keys, you might want to consider an object instead of an array to store them.

```
DataStructure.prototype.models = {
  rightPlace: new ModelPatternConstruct(),
  leftPlace: new ModelPatternConstruct()
}
// now you can modify them like you wanted
DataStructure.prototype.models.param1 = 5;
```

Or if you do the work inside your constructor: (the norm is to do simple key-value assignment inside the prototype function, and to add functions externally with `Object.prototype.myFunction = etc...`

```
function DataStructure() {
  this.models = {
    rightPlace: new ModelPatternConstruct(),
    leftPlace: new ModelPatternConstruct()
  }
  this.models.somePattern = new ModdelPatternConstruct();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed reply! So actually I used prototype because I thought I need it to have access to those variables and functions from other classes. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well not quite. If you only have one `DataStructure` object it doesn't make sense to build a constructor for it, rather use an object Literal then (`var DataStructure = {}`). It makes sense to have a prototype for your model patterns because you have more than one (and so that instances can inherit the prototype values, as you presumed).

Comment: So my DataStructure is built up like this: `var DataStructure = (function() { return DataStructure; }());` I have a Prototype for the default value array.

Comment: Yes, that works well too. you'd want to return `this` and not `DataStructure` though

Comment: Oh well i didn't know that there is a difference? So returning this has another behavior than returning DataStructure?

Comment: I was thinking that `DataStructure` and `this` behaves the same way when used in between the class. Thanks a lot for your help! I definitely need to get more into the theory of OOP in javascript.

Comment: As a final note, here's a great comprehensive intro into [OOJS](http://beardedocto.tumblr.com/post/21920818233/oo-js-in-15mins-or-less) and ['Javascript Design Patterns'](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) is a great book by Addy Osmani on well... what the title says.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I also appreciate the links that you shared. I will definitely take a deeper look at them!